# Adding delay to mouse out function in css dropdown menu

Tags: css

I want to add delay to the mouse out function about 1000ms
thanks

```
$('#cart .arrow').live('mouseover', function () {
    $('#cart').addClass('active');
    $('#cart').load('index.php?route=module/cart #cart > *');

    $('#cart > .content').slideToggle('fast');
    $('#cart').live('mouseleave', function () {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `setTimeout`

```
$('#cart').live('mouseleave', function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    }, 1000)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('#cart').addClass('active');

    $('#cart').load('index.php?route=module/cart #cart > *');

    $('#cart > .content').slideToggle('fast');

    $('#cart').live('mouseleave', function() 
    {

      setTimeout(function()
      {
       $(this).removeClass('active'); 
      }, 5000);

    });
```

This will cause a delay of 5 seconds on mouse out.

Comment: How this answer is different from the above answer?

Comment: By the time I answered this question, it was already answered.